# to save the data in multiple tables at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, rest, sugarcrm

I am working on the Node REST API's, in which I'm trying to import a CSV file in different- different tables of a database. I want to do it by a single function and for that, I have created an array and put 4 elements there. These elements are the modules and the tables of the DB as well.

I am checking the element of the array one by one and if a user selects an element then it will match the condition and import the file into the DB and return the data in the json format. For that I am also using 'sugarcrm-js-rest-consumer' npm package for browser and node.js. "sugar.setEntries" is the predefined method of that rest consumer.

I haven't added any csv import package yet in the code, please find my code below for better understanding. please help me solving this out.

**home.js**

```
/**
 * POST /importfile
 */
exports.importFile = (req, res) => {  
    //var selMod = req.body.selectedModule;
    console.log("req.body---------", req.body);
    var selMod = 'Accounts';

    if(req.body.sessionId != "")
    {   

        var modules = ['Contacts', 'Accounts', 'Leads', 'Opportunities'];

        if (modules.indexOf('Contacts')!=-1 && selMod=='Contacts') {
            console.log("Good day Contacts");
            // setEntries
            sugar.setEntries("Contacts", false, req.body.saveData).then(function(response)
            {
                res.send({status:'success',msg:'Contacts added successfully.',responseData:response['id']});  
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                res.send({status:'error',msg:'Unable to created Contacts.'}); 
            });
        }
        else if (modules.indexOf('Accounts')!=-1 && selMod=='Accounts') {
            console.log("Good day Accounts");
            sugar.setEntries("Accounts", false, req.body.saveData).then(function(response)
            {
                res.send({status:'success',msg:'Accounts added successfully.',responseData:response['id']});  
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                res.send({status:'error',msg:'Unable to created Accounts.'}); 
            });
        }
        else if (modules.indexOf('Leads')!=-1 && selMod=='Leads') {
            console.log("Good day Leads");
            sugar.setEntries("Leads", false, req.body.saveData).then(function(response)
            {
                res.send({status:'success',msg:'Leads added successfully.',responseData:response['id']});  
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                res.send({status:'error',msg:'Unable to created Leads.'}); 
            });
        }
        else if (modules.indexOf('Opportunities')!=-1 && selMod=='Opportunities') {
            console.log("Good day Opportunities");
            sugar.setEntries("Opportunities", false, req.body.saveData).then(function(response)
            {
                res.send({status:'success',msg:'Opportunities added successfully.',responseData:response['id']});  
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                res.send({status:'error',msg:'Unable to created Opportunities.'}); 
            });
        }    
    }
    else 
    {
        res.send({status:'error',msg:Constants.COMN_SESSION_MESSAGE}); 
    }
};
```

**index.php**

```
case '26':
        ?>
            <h3> Import data</h3>
            <form action="http://localhost:5000/importfile" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Select Module in which you want to import file<select name="modules" id="modules" title="">
                    <option label="Contacts" value="Contacts" selected="selected">Contacts</option>
                    <option label="Accounts" value="Accounts">Accounts</option>
                    <option label="Leads" value="Leads">Leads</option>
                    <option label="Opportunities" value="Opportunities">Opportunities</option>
                </select>  
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="file" name="fileUpload" value="fileUpload"> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  
                </td>
                </tr>    
            </table>            
            </form>
        <?php  
        break;
```

**index.js**

```
app.post('/importfile', homeController.isAuthenticated, homeController.importFile);
```

Comment: you can use `Promise.all`

Comment: @zabusa, can you give me a sort example of promise.all ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all